# RxJava flatMapIterable with a Single

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm trying to tidy up my code a little, and `Single` is looking like a good choice for me as I'm doing something that will only ever emit one result.

I'm having an issue though as I was using `flatMapIterable` previously to take my response (a list) and do something on each item.  I'm not seeing how I can achieve this with Single.

```
getListOfItems()
.flatMapIterable(items -> items)
.flatMap(item -> doSomethingWithItem())
.toList()
```

This works fine if `getListOfItems` is returning an `Observable` but if I try and make it return a `Single`, then I can't do `flatMapIterable` and can't see an alternative, any ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[flattenAsObservable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#flattenAsObservable(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) should do the trick, it will map `Single` success value to `Iterable` (list), and emit each item of the list as an `Observable`.

```
  getListOfItems()
            .flattenAsObservable(new Function<Object, Iterable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<?> apply(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                    return toItems(o);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(item -> doSomethingWithItem())
            .toList()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for

Comment: Single.flattenAsObservable doesn't exist. Was it a RxJava 1 thing? Is there a v2 equivalent?

Comment: @miguel, it's RxJava 2 only.

Comment: @miguel it only exists for Single and Maybe. Not for Observable, Flowable or Completable.

Answer (score 15):

Building on the answer from yosriz, this is what I ended up with in **Kotlin**

```
getListOfItems()
        .flattenAsObservable { it }
        .flatMap { doSomethingWithItem(it) }
        .toList()
```

The same can be achieved using Kotlin's `map`, depending on your preference:

```
getListOfItems()
        .map { items ->
            items.map {
                doSomethingWithItem(it)
            }
        }
```

Comment: In Kotlin you can even write `getListOfItems().map { items -> items.map { doSomethingWithItem(it) }`
While the first `map` is from RxJava and operates on the stream emission, the second one is from Kotlin and operates on the Iterable.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert `Single` to `Observable` by using operator `toObservable()`

It will look like this:

```
getListOfItems()
    .toObservable()
    .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
    .flatMap(item -> doSomethingWithItem())
    .toList()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made something like this

```
@Override
public Single<List<String>> getAvailablePaths() {
        return mongoClient.rxFind("t_polygons", new JsonObject())
                            .toObservable()
                            .flatMapIterable(list -> list)
                            .map(json -> json.getString("path"))
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                            .toList()
                            .toSingle();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by using `flatMapPublisher` and `Flowable::fromIterable`

```
getListOfItems()
    .flatMapPublisher(Flowable::fromIterable)
    .flatMap(item -> doSomethingWithItem())
    .toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getListOfItems()
  .flattenAsObservable { it }
  .flatMapSingle { getSingleDoSomeThing(it) }
  .toList()
```

Comment: This answer would be improved if you give an explanation of your code.